# ASP.Net URL Routing only works when `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is true

Tags: asp.net, web-config, url-routing

I have set up URL Routing in IIS. When I have the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` set to true, the URL routing works.

With the following web.config (and `runAllManagedModuesForAllRequests` set to false) I get a 404:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode"
           verb="*"
           path="UrlRouting.axd"
           type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
                     System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
                     Culture=neutral, 
                     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
            type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
                System.Web.Routing, 
                Version=3.5.0.0, 
                Culture=neutral, 
                PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

How do I set up URL Routing for only certain requests?

I have tested this configuration in IIS 7.5 and IIS 8. This is in a web forms application. All URLs demonstrate the 404 behavior.

Comment: IIS7? IIS7.5? IIS8? Which URLs? Extensionless?. Or it's an ASP.NET MVC app in which case you need to register your routes. Need more info.

Comment: Added a couple of sentences to the question body to answer your questions.

Comment: Extensionless and extension URLs? I.e. .aspx and no .aspx?

Comment: It's extensionless (no .aspx)

Answer (score 1):

"runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" being true, means that the asp.net handler (of course when you are in integrated mode) will fire for all extensions (including extension-less), if you don't have aspx and it's set to false your module can't process it.

You can't setup for a subset of extensions for what you are trying to achieve, but you can in the module filter it yourself to only handle certain extensions.